# On event executed multiple times after compilation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this directive:

```
    myApp.directive('someDir', function($compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$on("compileTask", function() {
                $compile(element)(scope);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And in my controller I am broadcasting the event as:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.$broadcast('compileTask');
}]);
```

And the view is:

```
<h2 some-dir ng-bind-html="employee.name"></h2>
<h4 some-dir ng-bind-html="employee.designation"></h4>
```

The problem is that, when the 'compileTask' event is broadcasted, It is broadcasted multiple times. i want to know why it is broadcasting the event multiple times? And what is the way to allow broadcast for single time

Comment: Are you sure that it is not because you are using multiple directives?

Comment: @RaghuVenmarathoor I see that, '<h2>' tag is compiled twice, once when it is compiled individually and next time along with '<h4>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is 'broadcasted' to all event listeners. Since you have two directives listening for the event, they will both handle it.

Comment: Yes, Is there any way to compile this two directive only once?